# pandoc document conversion failed with error 1 after update to R version 3.4.2

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

After updating to R Version 3.4.2 my flexdashboard documents with shiny do not work anymore.

Even if I try to run a copy of that example https://jjallaire.shinyapps.io/shiny-biclust/
I got that

> 'Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1'

.

Until now I did not find an answer to that error during my websearch.
I also updated all packages.

My sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] biclust_1.2.0    lattice_0.20-35  colorspace_1.3-2 MASS_7.3-47     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] flexclust_1.3-4   Rcpp_0.12.13      digest_0.6.12     rprojroot_1.2     jsonlite_1.5      backports_1.1.1  
 [7] stats4_3.4.2      magrittr_1.5      evaluate_0.10.1   stringi_1.1.5     rpart_4.1-11      rmarkdown_1.7    
[13] flexdashboard_0.5 tools_3.4.2       stringr_1.2.0     parallel_3.4.2    yaml_2.1.14       compiler_3.4.2   
[19] htmltools_0.3.6   knitr_1.17        modeltools_0.2-21
```

Has anyone an Idea what I could try to solve that?

**EDIT:**

Maybe this Info can help to find the reason of the Error:
When trying a copy of the "Diamond Explorer" example  https://jjallaire.shinyapps.io/shiny-ggplot2-diamonds/ the result is that:

[screenshot of my Diamond Explorer copy - result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auMuk.png)

and I can see that error Messages in RStudio:

```
Output created:  
C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMdOsLH/file1ce033bb6c82.html
Warnung: Error in sample.int: Objekt 'input' nicht gefunden
Stack trace (innermost first):
120: sample.int
119: sample
118: lapply
117: map
116: [.tbl_df
115: [ [<text>#2]
114: <reactive:dataset> [<text>#2]
103: dataset
102: ggplot [<text>#6]
101: renderPlot [<text>#6]
 91: <reactive:plotObj>
 80: plotObj
 79: origRenderFunc
 78: output$outcca1a5b38b4e8b1a
  3: <Anonymous>
  2: do.call
  1: rmarkdown::run
```

Comment: thank you for improving my question layout

Comment: Did you try updating your pandoc?

Comment: I just installed pandoc to Version 2.0.2. - but the error is still the same.

Comment: Maybe that is the reason for the error: When running above example I can see that in the RStudio RMarkdown-Tab:   pandoc.exe: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpILZYrg\rmarkdown-stre24630e29de.html: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory).

Comment: Try this `Sys.getenv('RSTUDIO_PANDOC')`

Comment: The result ist this:  "//xxx.org/HE$/userdata/xxx/Documents/RStudio/bin/pandoc"  So I copied the new pandoc.exe and pandoc-citeproc.exe in that Directory but that also does not help

Comment: Can you copy the same path and do this Sys.setenv(''RSTUDIO_PANDOC" = path) path is the copied path in quotes

Comment: When I set Sys.setenv('RSTUDIO_PANDOC'= "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Pandoc")  (= the path where pandoc 2.0.2 was automatically installed) the error is still the same, but after closing RStudio and open it again the path has changed again to "//xxx.org/HE$/userdata/xxx/Documents/RStudio/bin/pandoc''   Is there anything I have to change in  .Rprofile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for my problem:
After reading that  https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1184
and installing an actual rmarkdown package from github:
`devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`
my flexdashboard documents with shiny works again :-)

Comment: Encountered the same issue and this solved my problem as well. Thanks!